# org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot instantiate class Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng

I am getting these errors when running an automation script. I have looked at all the other similar posts but nothing solved the errors. The browser is opening on the correct address but the test does not seem to run. I didn't do automatic for a long time, hope you can help.

Here are the console logs:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 90.0.4430.24 (4c6d850f087da467d926e8eddb76550aed655991-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#429}) on port 16384
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
May 14, 2021 5:27:39 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class portalTestsuites.homePage
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.instantiateUsingDefaultConstructor(InstanceCreator.java:193)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstanceUsingObjectFactory(InstanceCreator.java:113)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstance(InstanceCreator.java:79)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:109)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:167)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:102)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:82)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:74)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:39)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:459)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:338)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:179)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:613)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:178)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1275)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1251)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1100)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:23)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.tryRead(NioSocketImpl.java:267)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:279)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:976)
    at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:355)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:227)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:215)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:105)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:155)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteTimeouts.implicitlyWait(RemoteWebDriver.java:776)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringTimeouts.implicitlyWait(EventFiringWebDriver.java:670)
    at com.portalHelpers.WebDriverHelper.<init>(WebDriverHelper.java:95)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:6)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
    at portalTestsuites.homePage.<init>(homePage.java:7)
```

- this is the base class with the driver methods:

  ```
  package com.portalHelpers;
  import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
  import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.util.Date;
  import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
  import org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;
  import org.slf4j.Logger;
  import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
  import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
  import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.Arrays;
  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
  import static java.lang.String.valueOf;

  public class WebDriverHelper extends EventFiringWebDriver {
        public static RemoteWebDriver remoteDriver;
        protected static HtmlUnitDriver htmlDriver;
        protected static Alert _alert;
        protected static DriverService cds;
        private static String driverClass = System.getProperty("driverClass");

        public static long now = new Date().getTime();
        public static com.itextpdf.text.Document dataFeed;

        public final static String DefaultTimeOut = "40000";
        public final static int TimeOut = 90;

        protected static String chrome_driver_location = "/Users/me/Downloads/chromedriver";

        public static String url = System.getProperty("url");
        public static String browser = System.getProperty("browser");
        private static String platform = Platform.getCurrent().name();
        private static String CHROME_DRIVER = "chrome_driver";


        //******************URLs************************************************************//

       public static String url_test = "https://www.google.com";
       public static String url_live = "https://www.google.com"
        //******************Browser settings************************************************************//

        //Browser settings

    static {
  //
                if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
                if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("Mac")) {
                    CHROME_DRIVER = CHROME_DRIVER + "_mac";
                } else if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("LINUX")) {
                    CHROME_DRIVER = CHROME_DRIVER + "_linux";
                } else {
                    CHROME_DRIVER = CHROME_DRIVER + "_win.exe";
                }
                setWebDriverToChrome();
            }


            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    remoteDriver.close();
                }
            });
        }

        static {
            if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("url_test")) {
                open_test();
            } else if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("url_live")) {
                open_live();

            }

        }

    public WebDriverHelper() {
            super(remoteDriver);
          //  manage().window().maximize();
            manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

        @BeforeMethod
        public void setUp ()  {

            setWebDriverToChrome();}


        @AfterTest
        public void tearDown () {
                remoteDriver.quit();

            }


        public static void setWebDriverToChrome () {

         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",chrome_driver_location);
            cds = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()

                    .usingDriverExecutable(new File(chrome_driver_location))
                    .usingAnyFreePort()
                    .build();

            try {
                cds.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e.getMessage());
            }

            ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
            opt.addArguments("disable-infobars");
            opt.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            opt.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
            remoteDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(cds.getUrl(), opt);
        }

        public void openWebPage (String url){

            //Get url and maximize the window
            remoteDriver.get(url);
           // remoteDriver.manage().window().maximize();
        }

        public static void open_test () {
            remoteDriver.get(url_test);
           // remoteDriver.manage().window().maximize();

        }

        public static void open_live() {
            remoteDriver.get(url_live);
           // remoteDriver.manage().window().maximize();

        }

        public static WebDriver getSelenium () {
            if ((remoteDriver == null) && (!"noBrowser".equals(driverClass))) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Selenium client is not initialised.");
            }
            return remoteDriver;
        }
  }
  ```

The Test class:

```
package portalTestsuites;
import com.portalHelpers.WebDriverHelper;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class homePage extends WebDriverHelper {
homePage homepage= new homePage();
WebDriverHelper webDriverHelper = new WebDriverHelper();

@Test(groups = "HomePageTests")
public void homeUrl(){
String actual_url = webDriverHelper.getCurrentUrl();
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you using ```homePage homepage= new homePage();
WebDriverHelper webDriverHelper = new WebDriverHelper();``` these lines in your test class? your class is extending webDriverHelper and you are creating homepage object of the same class. Can you remove these 2 lines and rerun?

Comment: When removing both, It didn't work. Removing only the homepage one made it work. Since I am still using methods from WebdriverHelper. Thanks, I missed that one.

Comment: you should ideally be able to remove ```WebDriverHelper webDriverHelper = new WebDriverHelper();``` as well and change the line ```String actual_url = webDriverHelper.getCurrentUrl();``` to ```String actual_url = getCurrentUrl();```

Comment: Great it works like that as well. thanks so much.